# Add Material Icon inside MaterializeCss Toast?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Is it possible to add an icon inside a materializecss toast message?

I tried doing it like this but got '[object-object]' returned inside the toast:

```
var $printerIcon = $('<i class="material-icons print"></i>');

Materialize.toast($printerIcon + 'Your print job was sent',4000);
```

Answer (score 2):

it's just show the icon , not with text,,

for icon with text try this :

```
const Icon = '<i class="material-icons print">done_all</i>';
const Message = 'Your print job was sent';
const $toast = Icon +Message ;
Materialize.toast( $toast, 4000);
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that Javascript tries to convert `$printerIcon + 'Your print job was sent'` to a string.

Try adding the text inside the markup like so:

```
const printerIcon = '<i class="material-icons print"></i>';
const toastMessage = 'Your print job was sent';
const $toastContent = $( `${ printerIcon } ${ toastMessage }` );
Materialize.toast( $toastContent, 4000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with css only by using :before

```
#toast-container{

    .toast{     

        &:before{
        content: “your-icon”;

    }

}
```

Watch this example below:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrGmeg